# Analog "And" gate

Tags: transistors, analog

Is there any possible way to make something similar to an analog and gate? Basically I was thinking something so that if fed two inputs, it would take the lower of the two.
EX:
5v+5v=>5v
5v+1v=>1v
2v+3v=>2v

Is there any way to do this without having to be strictly on and off like a digital signal, but rather keep the signal in tact (for something like an audio signal perhaps)?

Answer (score 5):

It does not seem to be an AND gate analog.

It's a "most negative" voting circuit or ...

Have a look at this circuit.
 May need minor additions in practice. Or not.
 Vins to non-inverting inputs.
 R to suit. Say 10k probably OK.

Work out what it does.
 See if it meets your need.

[image]

This can be thought of as a pair of what are sometimes referred to as "perfect diodes" - but with a twist. Each op amp senses the output and if it is above its Vin it drives the output down until Vout = Vin.
 BUT if Vout > Vin it TRIES to drive the output high so can not affect the output.

Comment: Could you explain how that circuit works, Russell?

Comment: @abdullah It works similar to the simplest precision rectifier circuit. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier

Comment: @starblue, so D1 and D2 is placed reversed here by mistake?

Comment: No, they are reversed because you want the *minimum*.

Comment: You could achieve almost the same effect with just the diodes. The op-amps merely buffer the input circuits.. and null the diode drops, but that's just getting fancy. In essence, this is just a pair of "voltage clamp" diodes.

Comment: @JustJeff - not wity any sor of precision s b=normally indrsrood.

Comment: @JustJeff - For some values of "almost", sure. But not with any sort of precision as the term is normally understood. eg he gives an example of 2V and 3V inputs. Depending on input impedance, diode type and more the output would typically be 0.3 to say 0.8V above Vin min. At 0.3V diode drop and Vin = 2V, 3V then vout = 2.3V. That's fine if you want to save every last RMB but a difference of 0.3/2 = 15% seems "a bit rough" . || If I was going say "this is just a ..." then "Just a pair of "perfect diodes" is what 1st comes to mind.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I took Jeffs comment as just trying to help break this down into its parts to help the OP understand what is going on.

Comment: The circuit in the schematic is good from a conceptual standpoint, but its behavior with certain op amps may be less than ideal.  If, e.g., the left is more positive than the other, then the inverting input on the left amp will be lower than the non-inverting input, and even if the amp swings to the rail that will continue to be true.  If the left input then becomes more negative than the right one, it may take awhile for the op amp to reach the proper voltage.  Depending upon the design of its compensation network, it might overshoot.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if what I said sounded dismissive or something - @Kellenjb read it the way I meant it. Just wanted to give beginners an idea of how to analyze it.

Comment: @supercat - Agree. As in my "May need minor additions in practice. Or not." I scribbled that out as a guide to the principle. A bit of beating into shape may be needed :-).

Comment: I like it very much. It has also the advantage of being expandable for more inputs very easily.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement this with two chips, an analog comparator and a a 2:1 analog mux.

Connect one of the voltage inputs to the positive comparator input and the mux input that will be selected when the mux control input is driven low.

Connect the other voltage input to the negative comparator input and the other mux input.

Connect the comparator output to the mux control input.

The Mux output will then always be switched to the lower of the two inputs.

As with any analog circuit implementation, make sure that you select components with datasheet specified voltage ranges that are adequate for your circuit and connect the power inputs to appropriate voltage rails with appropriate bypass capacitance.  If you choose a comparator with an open collector (or drain) output, add the appropriate pull up resistor.

Comment: this strikes me as a more robust solution of the two presented, nice modularity!

Comment: I like Russell's circuit better because there is no deliberate descision required, with its possible associated glitch when switching over.  Russell's automatically puts out the minimum of the two voltages.

Comment: Both circuits have advantages.  The multiplexer approach will yield an output which more faithfully tracks the lower input when the two inputs are not crossing over each other.  A diode-based approach may, if carefully tweaked, more accurately track the actual minimum during the time that the two signals are crossing than could a multiplexer-based approach.  Which is better would depend upon the application.

Comment: I think the approach of using a comparator and analog mux is not a good idea at all. Just imagine the two input voltages may be almost identical and there is some noise (and there always is noise): the comperator will be switching  very quickly back and forth. The fast changing digital comparator output signal being very close to the analog lines will only bring trouble.

Comment: @Curd: Yes, if the inputs are very close in value, and the noise is greater than the hysteresis of the comparator, the comparator output could chatter.  Since we don't know much about the application, I'm not sure how likely that is. Adding circuitry to increase the hysteresis would be necessary if the inherent hysteresis if the comparator is insufficient to prevent spurous output switching.

Comment: @B Pete: ...but adding hysteresis to the comparator deteriorates accuracy