# OPAMP has voltage on its supply when it shouldn't

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, comparator

I was trying to design a circuit after seeing [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/24064/5035) question. I know I used too much components than I should designing a circuit with this purpose. And sorry about the messiness of the schematic.

This circuit compares V1 and V2 and if V2>V1 than it outputs V2. If V1>V2, it outputs V1. I am going to combine U2 and U3's outputs later on. However I don't understand why this circuit behaves abnormally.

Even if the Q2's base shown to have about 20mV, Vbe of Q2 is negative, and V+ supply pin of U3 is 2.42V. Output of U1 is 8.39V and collector of Q3 is about 20mV. Output of U2 is 5V, where the output of U3 is 1.57V.

Why is this odd behavior?

[image: avct]

[Here](http://www.mediafire.com/?lgghugofv3ttf07) is the LTspice file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of possibilities spring to mind:

One is that since the input is higher than V+, there is leakage through causing V+ to rise.
This looks quite possible since V+ appears to be about a diode drop from the input voltage (3V - 0.6V = 2.4V)
Most opamps don't like an input voltage higher than the supply.

The other thing to bear in mind is that the opamp model may not simulate accurately when used like this. Most are behavioural models rather than transistor models.
Some models do funny things when used in non obvious ways, so it may not be doing exactly what it would in real life. I think it looks reasonable though.
For interests sake, you could try putting a load on the output (and maybe a series resistor on the input) and see if it drops. Also you could change the input voltage to see if the V+ follows it (minus 0.6V)

A better solution to switching the opamp supply would be to do something like use an opamp with an enable input to switch on/off, or put an analogue switch before/after the opamps to cut the signal. A multiplexer like a 4052 would work okay (you can simulate it with the voltage controlled switch component if you can't find a model)

An analogue switch can be as simple as a PMOS:

[image: PMOS Switch]

This can't handle signals that swing negative though, for that you need something like this:

[image: PMOS/NMOS Switch]

This configuration is used in most analogue switch ICs.

The 4052 (or 4053 could be used) suggested is basically just a few of these in one package, with some logic to switch between them.
For comparison, here is a diagram of one of the internal switches of a 4053:

[image: 4053 internal]

Comment: Yup, it follows the non-inverting input. 1kohm load doesn't effect it much, however dropping the load resistance(increasing the load) affects it. @100ohms load, V+ is 1.64V where niinput is 3V. An analog switch is a MOSFET or such, in simple terms, right? I mean do I need to have a multiplexer here?

Comment: You don't have to use a "dedicated" multiplexer, you could use two analogue switches instead (which can be as simple as a single PMOS) I edited the answer with some more info.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the LT1006 has some kind of protection diodes on its input; the voltage from your 3 volt supply attached to the non-inverting input of U3 is appearing at the power supply input, less the voltage drop across the diode.  I'm not sure if they would be included in the SPICE model, though. Trying to do what you're trying to do by switching on and off the power supplies is a sub-optimal solution for a number of other reasons, however, such as the fact that you're compromising your output swing on U2 and U3 due to their respective supply switching transistor's Vbe drop.  Surely there's another way to do what you wish to do?

Comment: I am sure there is an another way to do this, I would be glad If someone leads me to it.

Comment: Oli's answer might have had more diagrams, but this answer tells you why the circuit would have that behavior in real life. Applying voltage to the input of an unpowered IC is generally likely to result in trying to power the whole circuit through that input pin.